# How to generate all possible consecutive n-tuples of a vector in R?

Tags: r, list, vector

How to generate all possible consecutive n-tuples of a vector in R?

```
# Input 
x <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'b')
n = 2
```

```
# Output 
list(c('a', 'b'), c('b', 'c'), c('c', 'b')) # a list equal to this list
```

Comment: akrun's answer is spot on, but you might also consider `embed(x, n)`. (you would need to reverse each row though, i.e. `embed(x, n)[,seq(n, 1)]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
lapply(1:(length(x) - n + 1), \(i) x[i:(i + n - 1)])

# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "b"

# [[2]]
# [1] "b" "c"

# [[3]]
# [1] "c" "b"
```

Answer (score 3):

We may remove the first and last elements and concatenate by looping over the corresponding elements with `Map`

```
Map(c, x[-length(x)], x[-1])
$a
[1] "a" "b"

$b
[1] "b" "c"

$c
[1] "c" "b"
```

---

Or `cbind` to a `matrix` and split by row with `asplit`

```
asplit(cbind(x[-length(x)], x[-1]), 1)
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "c"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "b"
```

---

If the `n` values can be more than 2, we may also do this with `shift`

```
library(data.table)
Filter(\(x) all(complete.cases(x)), 
  data.table::transpose(shift(x, seq_len(n)-1, type = 'lead')))
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "c"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "b"
```

Answer (score 3):

Vectorized Base **R** solution (I don't use `embed` or `asplit`; they have a `for`-loop inside).

```
foo <- function (x, n = 2, format = "matrix") {
  m <- length(x) - n + 1
  y <- x[sequence(rep(m, n), 1:n)]
  if (format == "matrix") matrix(y, ncol = n)
  else if (format == "list") split(y, 1:m)
  else stop("unknown format!")
}
```

```
foo(x, 2, "matrix")
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "a"  "b" 
#[2,] "b"  "c" 
#[3,] "c"  "b" 

foo(x, 3, "matrix")
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
#[2,] "b"  "c"  "b" 

foo(x, 2, "list")
#$`1`
#[1] "a" "b"
#
#$`2`
#[1] "b" "c"
#
#$`3`
#[1] "c" "b"

foo(x, 3, "list")
#$`1`
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
#
#$`2`
#[1] "b" "c" "b"
```

---

> Could you simplify the function please? Remove `format`.

A straightforward one line:

```
split(x[sequence(rep(length(x) - n + 1, n), 1:n)], seq_len(length(x) - n + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some fun.

```
fun1 <- function (x, n) asplit(embed(x, n)[, n:1], 1)

fun2 <- function (x, n) split(x[sequence(rep(length(x) - n + 1, n), 1:n)], seq_len(length(x) - n + 1))

fun3 <- function (x, n) lapply(1:(length(x) - n + 1), \(i) x[i:(i + n - 1)])

library(microbenchmark)

x <- 1:10000
microbenchmark("for" = fun1(x, 2), "split" = fun2(x, 2), "lapply" = fun3(x, 2))
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#    for 30.536090 39.196876 49.400427 48.541195 55.481533 107.46441   100   c
#  split  6.453484  7.049844  7.765709  7.647299  7.904683  13.63022   100 a  
# lapply 16.070532 21.959815 26.988959 28.482102 31.133325  45.47318   100  b 

microbenchmark("for" = fun1(x, 10), "split" = fun2(x, 10), "lapply" = fun3(x, 10))
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#    for 34.115408 34.826142 39.136366 35.631689 37.200893 200.63875   100   c
#  split  8.566762  8.780026  9.255456  9.057524  9.641736  12.67383   100 a  
# lapply 17.343556 17.845281 19.289687 18.301174 18.833777  28.19920   100  b 

microbenchmark("for" = fun1(x, 20), "split" = fun2(x, 20), "lapply" = fun3(x, 20))
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#    for 38.33747 38.90368 40.61395 39.72388 40.64009 51.51035   100   c
#  split 11.29013 11.39768 12.07148 11.48208 12.13088 17.46919   100 a  
# lapply 18.77825 18.94005 20.88440 19.33751 19.93676 42.35469   100  b
```

Comment: The `split` option is faster but I prefer the conciseness of the `apply` one